# Why can't swift find my MOV file in my app bundle?

Tags: swift

I am trying to find a mov file "mymovie.MOV", but so far the path is not being found. I have added it to my project. It is listed under "Copy Bundle Resources." It is also included in target membership for my project. I have also tried cleaning the build folder and restarting Xcode.

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mymovie", ofType: "mov") else{
            print("Path not found.")
            return
        }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a discrepancy here:

> a mov file "mymovie.MOV"

and

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mymovie", ofType: "mov")
```

Those don't go together. `"mov"` is not the same as `"MOV"`. Which is it? They need to be both the same.